# MongoError:"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query","code":16604,"codeName":"Location16604"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, geonear

I am frustrated about mongodb geonear aggregate query, for each response i get error like this :

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query: ns=Lab.assoprofiles limit=100Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=50000 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: { $pt: { $meta: \"geoNearPoin...\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\" }","ok":0,"errmsg":"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query: ns=Lab.assoprofiles limit=100Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=50000 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: { $pt: { $meta: \"geoNearPoin...\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\" }","code":16604,"codeName":"Location16604"}
```

This how i designed the collection :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AssoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userId:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
   picture : String,
   telephone: {
      type: String,
      unique: false
   },
   loc: {
      type: [Number], // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
      index: "2d" // create the geospatial index
   },

},{timestamps: true})

var Asso = mongoose.model('AssoProfile', AssoSchema);
module.exports = Asso;
```

And query is like this :

```
const latitude = parseFloat(req.body.latitude);
const longitude = parseFloat(req.body.longitude);
AssoProfile.aggregate([
     {
        $geoNear: {
           near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [latitude, longitude] },
           spherical: true, distanceField: 'distance', maxDistance:7000,
        }
     }

   ], function(err, l ){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log(l);
   })
```

I don't understand why such simple query throws this error. 
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Well I know you are asking this question 3rd or 4th time... And that's why I searched for it and I think may be i got the answer...  which version of node and mongodb and mongoose you are using?

Comment: Hi : node ==> v8.9.1, mongodb ==> v4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run same code you have posted above but It didn't work for me... And I think  **`index: 2d`** is not an option in mongoose model. And instead I have created index like this and worked for me.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var AssoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
   picture : String,
   telephone: {
      type: String,
      unique: false
   },
   loc: Array,

}, { timestamps: true })


AssoSchema.index({ 'loc': '2dsphere' })

var Asso = mongoose.model('AssoProfile', AssoSchema)
module.exports = Asso;
```

Comment: Hi, yes i confirm 2dsphere is working, thank you. But i still wonder why 2d index not working

Comment: ***And I think  index: 2d is not a option in mongoose model*** I didn't see any where

Comment: Interesting, i have a developer who used 2d with mongoose and working well